# Pandas missing read_parquet function in Azure Databricks Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

When I use pandas to read parquet file in databricks notebook, following error happens: AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_parquet'. Tried installing newest version of pandas on my cluster but still no change. Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read parquet format file in Azure Databricks notebook, you should directly use the class [`pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader) to do that to load data as a PySpark dataframe, not use `pandas`.

Here is code sample.

```
df = spark.read.format("parquet").load('<the path of your parquet file>')
```

or

```
df = spark.read.parquet('<the path of your parquet file>')
```

If you want to get pandas dataframe from PySpark dataframe, you can use the function [`toPandas()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas) of a PySpark dataframe below.

```
pdf = df.toPandas()
```

---

Update: I checked the `pandas` version in the default Azure databricks notebook via the code below, I found it's `0.19.2`.

[image]

So you must have to upgrade the `pandas` version more than and equals `0.21.x` which be the first version supports `read_parquet` function from the `pandas/io/parquet.py` as the figure below.

[image]

To upgrade `pandas` in your databricks cluster, please follow the section [`Library utilities`](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#library-utilities) of the databricks offical document `Databricks Utilities` to install different version of `pandas` package, as the code and figure below.

```
dbutils.library.installPyPI("pandas", version="0.24.2")
dbutils.library.restartPython()
```

[image]

Then you can use the funciton `read_parquet` as the pandas offical document said.

[image]

Comment: For now I use pyspark, but the issue with ingesting with pyspark then transforming data into pandas data frame is it takes way too long, like over 30 minutes for 100M rows. I just want to test with pandas to directly read parquet and see if this way will reduce time.

Comment: @zzzk I have update my post. If it helps, please help me to mark it as answer.

Comment: Do you have any idea of how to uninstall the pandas library? After updating the library as you show, there is an issue about multiple numpy libraries which cause my cluster to not start.